# Software publishing in AD

Tags: active-directory, deployment

I need to deploy a package that creates a service on the client's machine.  I published it in AD so that it is available however, when the client attempts to install, there is a permission error in creating the service.

How do I enable end users to perform the installation from the control panel?

Thanks

Comment: msiexec /i \\server\sdp\software.msi is failing with the same error.   The installation gets about half way then chokes on creating the service.

Comment: If a manual `msiexec` is also failing, it's probably time to contact the vendor and ask them to fix their MSI.

Comment: Which version of Windows is the client running? You may run into more security issues with Windows 7 and UAC, depending on your environment's security policies.

Comment: Thanks, I tried testing with XP and Win7 (uac on and off) but to no avail.  If I copy the msi to the desktop, the install runs ok.